# How to convert a MySQL select statement with a subquery to the same table into an update statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, subquery

I have the following working select statement.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.option_key, ( 
    SELECT
        t3.content AS option_value
    FROM tblfoo t2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tblbar t3 ON( t3.refid = t2.id )
    WHERE t2.id = t1.id
    LIMIT 1
) AS option_value
FROM tblfoo t1
```

The table structure looks like the following:

```
| tblfoo                         |
+----+------------+--------------+
| id | option_key | option_value |
+----+------------+--------------+
|  1 | foo        | NULL         |
|  2 | bar        | NULL         |
|  3 | baz        | NULL         |


| tblbar               |
+----+-----------------+
| id | refid | content |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 |     1 | value1  |
|  1 |     2 | value2  |
|  1 |     3 | value3  |
```

The result of the update statement should be this:

```
| tblfoo                         |
+----+------------+--------------+
| id | option_key | option_value |
+----+------------+--------------+
|  1 | foo        | value1       |
|  2 | bar        | value2       |
|  3 | baz        | value3       |
```

I want to update `option_value` with `tblfoo` with the related data from `content` from `tblbar`. Unfortunately, `tblbar` may have multiple entries for the `refid` with the same value. This is why there is a need for `LIMIT 1` (or `GROUP BY t,id` or `DISTINCT`) with the subquery.

I have figured out, that the query is significant faster, when I do subquery with `LIMIT 1` instead of subquery with `SELECT DISTINCT` or a join in combination with `GROUP BY t1.id`. So after execution time optimization, I ended up with the select statement above.

There is also a catch with the source table, which should be updated. `option_value` is a actual field, that also exists in the source table (but with a `NULL` value).

The issues I ran into while trying to convert the optimized select statement above into an update statement was mainly that I cannot access `t1.id` from inside the subquery.

How to convert the select statement into an update statement without losing the performance optimization?

Comment: Which tables/columns are being updated with which data?

Comment: In the subquery, why do you join table2 and table3; I believe you can directly use table3

Comment: show the code you are trying for update

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have edited my question with the table structure and a more clearer desciption which fields should be updated.

Comment: If there are duplicate values, which one do you want to use?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The values of `option_value` are the same with that field. Other not mentioned fields of `tblbar` have different values. It is not normalized but I am not allowed to change the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an update join with a subquery which finds distinct values in `tblbar`:

```
UPDATE tblfoo f
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT refid, content
    FROM tblbar
) b
    ON f.id = b.refid
SET f.option_value = b.content;
```

Comment: thank you, your SQL works but with one alteration: it is `SET f.content = b.option_value;`. Can you update your answer? Then I can accept it :)

Comment: @burnersk Actually, my answer seems correct based on the tables you actually showed us.  If not, then update your question.

Comment: sorry, you are correct. That company restriction that I have to anonymize everything is killing me.

Answer (score 1):

Your correlated subquery can further be optimized by avoid the `Left Join` between the two tables. Instead, you can directly get the `content` value from the second table.

For updating, you can use your `select` query as a Derived table, and join it to the source table:

```
UPDATE tblfoo AS tfoo 
JOIN (
      SELECT t1.id, 
             (SELECT t3.content AS option_value
              FROM tblbar t3
              WHERE t3.refid = t1.id
              LIMIT 1
             ) AS option_value
      FROM tblfoo t1
     ) AS dt ON dt.id = tfoo.id 
SET tfoo.option_value = dt.option_value;
```

Comment: Your update statement works. However the version of @TimBiegeleisen is working faster (1 minute vs 10 minutes)

Comment: @burnersk yeah Tim optimized further. I did not optimize your original query as whole; just the subquery part.

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating all rows, then the most efficient method might be:

```
UPDATE tblfoo f
    SET f.option_value = (SELECT b.content FROM tblbar WHERE f.id = b.refid LIMIT 1);
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `tblbar(refid, content)`.